# Как распознать код морзе с помощью микрофона? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Всем привет, мне понадобилось написать программу конвертирующую код морзе с микрофона в текст.
К примеру мы воспроизводим звук из этого видео https://youtu.be/QJeCAvq4URU с другого устройства и на выходе получаем текст в консоль
...---...

Я искал решение этой задачи недели две, но ни смог найти ничего что могло бы мне помочь.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно решить данную задачу и какие библиотеки использовать?
(если они конечно есть)

Comment: librosa для анализа аудио

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Превращаешь аудио в массив таймингов, когда есть звук. Наличие звука определяем по тому, превышает ли громкость некий порог (скорее всего есть 2 наиболее распространённых уровня, но можно начать со среднего между минимум и максимумом).
2. По правилам тире в 3 раза больше точки, так что я бы взял минимальный по длительности сигнал, отфильтровал все сигналы, превышающие его менее чем в 2 раза и принял среднее за единицу.
3. Превращаем имеющийся массив в массив (или генератор) чего-то такого (должен получиться непрерывный таймлайн; время округляем до ближайшего допустимого значения):

   ```
   interface Entry {
     сигналИлиТишина: сигнал | тишина;
     длительность: 1 | 3 | 7; // 7 - только для тишины
   }
   ```
4. Выкидываем первую тишину если она есть. Убеждаемся, что последний элемент - (тишина,3). Если там сигнал, надо добавить ещё одну запись (чтобы не потерять последнюю букву), а если (тишина,7) то поменять 7 на 3 (чтобы не ставить в конце текста пробел).
5. Очевидно, что сигнал и тишина чередуются.

   ```
    буква = ""
    текст = ""

    for тип,длительность in ...:
      if тип == сигнал:
        буква += "." if длительность == 1 else "-"
      else if длительность > 1:
        текст += кодВСимвол(буква)
        if длительность == 7: текст += " "
        буква = ""

    print(текст)
   ```

PS: А вообще, вполне может быть, что для этого есть библиотека...